# Find statement + -exec -rm -r is not working, syntax issues? / bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm having issues with this statement, have no idea why it's not working, probably having syntax problem but can't figure out where. Script should find directories that contains in name @tmp or numbers with dots, and after finding a match - remove them. But it's not happening.

```
   find /home/user/data/ -type d \( -name "*@tmp" -o -regex "[0-9\.\/]+" \) -exec rm -r {} \;
```

Comment: What if you remove the `-exec` part and just let it print what it finds?  What does it find?

Comment: It doesn't show anything, but such files exists, even at the begining of scrpt i've `cd /home/user/somedir/`

Comment: Why is it `*\@\tmp` instead of just `*@tmp`?

Comment: To prevent Linux thinking it's a commend instead of part of statement. Also it can't find any file described by -regex

Comment: ive pasted whole script, maybe bug is in another place..

Comment: A proper [mcve] would be code someone else could run (not just you!) to see the problem ourselves. If the script in your question created a temporary directory with a file in it that *should* be deleted, for instance, that would (1) ensure that the question includes the exact name of the file that should be deleted but isn't; (2) test if a modified version of the command with a proposed fix *actually* deletes it; (3) test the same command against different versions of `find`; etc.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for:

```
find . -type d \( -name '*@tmp*' -o -regex '.*/[0-9.]+' \) ...
```

There's nothing magical about `@` or `t` that require them to be escaped, and regex matches the whole path so you need to match the leading elements.

Comment: It's probably worth amplifying that the `-delete` is an optimization (avoiding the overhead of executing an external `rm` instance) as opposed to the essential element of the fix (modifying the regex to match paths as opposed to bare names, and modifying the `-name` pattern to match `@tmp` *anywhere* in the name -- as the OP's prose requests -- as opposed to only at the end -- as their code implements).

Comment: I usually use -delete instead of `rm` to avoid spurious error messages arising from attempts to use `rm` to remove directories and to prevent attempts to apply `rmdir` to remove non-empty directories.  It looks like in this case the OP wants to apply the sledge hammer `rm -r`, so `-delete` may not do what is wanted since it will not remove directories that are not empty.  But....it is not an essential component of the question.